# Problems transfering data between activities. The app stops working on button click

Tags: android

I have a problem in transferring data between screens.
I have used intent .
below are my code.

This is a code in my parent class:

```
    final EditText ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText05);       
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(S1.this,S2.class);

            i.putExtra("ed1",ed1.getText().toString());

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

This is a code in my child class:

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yo);

    tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ed1"));
```

when I run the app it stops working and shows the following in logcat:

```
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923): Process: com.app.experiment, PID: 923
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923): java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at com.app.experiment.S1$1.onClick(S1.java:56)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    04-11 21:32:32.698: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my xml file where I have the button:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >                     

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="@string/Starters"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/submit"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/Submit" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the xml where I have the textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="textview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the xml having edittexts:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="#43bd00"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText05"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText06"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText05"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my S1.class:

```
 public class S1 extends ListActivity {
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 ListView lv;
 TextView starters,tx1;
 int key = 0;
 private static String url = "http://ashapurasoftech.com/train/test.json";
 private static final String TAG_a = "menu";
 private static final String TAG_Name = "Name";
 JSONArray items = null;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.table1);
    final EditText ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_06);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(S1.this,S2.class);
            i.putExtra("ed1",ed1.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    lv =getListView();
    starters = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    starters.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (key==0){
                key=1;
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else if(key==1) {
                    key=0;              
                    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }               
        }
    });
    itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        SingleContactActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_Name, name);
        startActivity(in);
        }
    });
new Getitems().execute();
       }
private class Getitems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();           
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(S1.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_a);
                                 for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String name = c.getString(TAG_Name);
                    item.put(TAG_Name, name);
                    itemList.add(item);         
                }}
                catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}}
        else {Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");}
        return null;    }
        @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        S1.this, itemList,
        R.layout.textview, new String[] {TAG_Name},new int[] { R.id.name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);            
        }}}
```

This is my S2.class:

```
        public class S2 extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yo);
                    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_06);
    tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("ed1"));
        } }
```

This Is my SingleContactActivity.class:

```
       public class SingleContactActivity  extends Activity {

private static final String TAG_Name = "Name";
@Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.textview);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_Name);
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    lblName.setText(name);
    }}
```

Comment: You've got NPE. Post activity code and xml files.

Comment: u got a NullPointerException on the onClick. It's probably caused because ed1 is null, is the ID typed correctly? btw- you can press "debug" (near run) to go step by step and see what and why this happens. This is a pretty typical error and you should learn to debug it yourself.

Comment: Done  xml files @Onik

Comment: There is no EditText at all in your xmls. When you're trying to retrieve a value in line ed1.getText().toString(), you get NPE.

Comment: I have another xml file having edittexts. I have posted that xml now @Onik

Comment: I actually cant debug in my eclipse there is some problem when I setp into next line it doesn't step.@rupps

Comment: @Deepii What layout do you set in setContentView() of MainActivity. Also, what are your xml files names? And the main question...why do you use different layouts containing Button and EditText??? They both have to be in one xml file.

Comment: setContentView() has table1 as layout. And my xml files name are table1.xml having the listviews and textview.xml having the edittext. I use different layouts because my app needs edittexts inside a listview so ihave used two layouts @Onik

Comment: @Deepii ...it's confusing without seeing the whole code. Please, post it all in order for us to help you.

Comment: What is on line 56 of S1.java?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(S1.this,S2.class); @Karakuri

Comment: posted the class files @Onik

Comment: @Deepii You're using R.id.edit_text_06 for EditText in S1 with setContentView(R.layout.table1) and the same id (R.id.edit_text_06) for TextView in S2 with setContentView(R.layout.yo). Since you have only one reference to edit_text_06 in R.java you'll probably get whether NPE in S1 or ClassCastException in S2.

Comment: I have R.id.edit_text_06 in the textview.xml and in S1.class I have to use table1.xml as layout as I need to display that layout when S1.class is called @Onik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Android specifically and Java in general, since most errors will crash your program, learn to test everything, and log unexpected conditions...

try this for the onclick listener:

```
if(ed1 != null){
  CharSequence charSequence = ed1.getText();
  if(text != null){
    text = charSequence.toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(S1.this,S2.class);
    i.putExtra("ed1",text);
    startActivity(i);
  } else {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "text is null");
  }
} else {
  Log.d("DEBUG", "ed1 is null");
}
```

And the other block might look like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yo);
if(tv != null){
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if(extras != null){
    String text = extras.getString("ed1");
    if(text != null){
      tv.setText(text);
    } else {
      Log.d("DEBUG", "text is null");
    }
  } else {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "extras is null")
  }
} else {
  Log.d("DEBUG", "tv is null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `EditText.getText()` can return null.

Comment: Can you provide more context for the OP?

Comment: No, that is the answer.  It returns null, the OP assumed it couldn't, and thus dereferenced it causing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot declare your EditText as final because it means that it wouldn't memorize new text and it will always point to initialization value that is null, so you have the nullpointer exception. Try to clear final in declaretion of ed1 and let us now.

Comment: I have declared edittext as final. Plz refer my code as class files I have posted

Comment: this part "I think you cannot declare your EditText as final because it means that it wouldn't memorize new text" is not correct.  Declaring it final would mean that variable could not be reassigned to another instance, but it would not affect the behavior of the EditText whatsoever.

Comment: @ Big MoMo. Ok I think I understand where I was wrong: final means that you cannot modify it in a single instance, so of course you can edit it even if you declare it final and memorize it. But perhapse I wasn't totally wrong because if you memorize null at beginning you can have nullPointErrorExceptio, or not? Let me know, please. Thanks for your correction.